# ios NSDictionary always shows up empty

Tags: ios

## h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface LoginViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDictionary *_data;

@end
```

## m

```
#import "LoginViewController.h"
#import "XMLReader.h"

@implementation LoginViewController

static NSDictionary *_raceInformation;

@synthesize _data, bibInput, lastNameInput, error;

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder 
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        NSError *e = [NSError alloc];
        NSString *xml = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"testhalfmarathon" ofType:@"xml"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&e];

        NSDictionary *asdf = [XMLReader dictionaryForXMLString:xml error:nil];
        self._data = [XMLReader dictionaryForXMLString:xml error:nil];

        //[xml release];
        //[e release];

        // !! BREAKPOINT HERE
    }
    return self;
}
```

When I hit the breakpoint, the *value* for `self._data` is `nil`. However, the *value* for `asdf` is the correct dictionary value I would expect in `self._data`. What gives?

*backstory:* I'm a n00b when it comes to `MRC` as I usually use `ARC`/`GC` languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What line of code did you put the breakpoint against? If it was just a blank line it will actually break at the previous valid line of code, which may have been before self._data was set.

Try putting NSLog(@"data %@", self._data); instead of your breakpoint and see what gets logged.

BTW, I see you had [xml release], which you commented out, presumably because it wasn't working. The reason this line is wrong is that [XMLReader dictionaryForXMLString...] returns an autoreleased object that shouldn't be released again.

In general, in Objective-C if a method name doesn't begin with "new", "alloc" or "copy" then it returns an autoreleased object that you don't need to release yourself.

Comment: It looks like this was working the whole time, but for some whacky reason the *value* of `self._dict` is `<nil>`. I also found out that adding `NSDictionary *asdf = self._data;` just after *assigning* `self._data` that `asdf` shows up as the correct data! *bizarre*.